Alternate to Parallel task execution in Azure DevOps pipeline
My Build Pipeline has multiple "Push Image to Registry" tasks.
Each of these tasks pushes to multiple different container registries authenticated using different service connections present in the Azure DevOps Project.
I am trying create 1 Powershell script task; utilizing something like ForEach-Object -Parallel and push to each registry at once.
Problem:
Not able to figure out how to connect to each of the different registries using the diff Service Connections in Powershell script
1 is Azure container registry and Serv Conn Type is Azure Resource Manager with SPN Auth
2nd is GCP container reg and Serv Conn Type is Docker Registry using basic auth

Can you share a [mre] of the two task you want to run parallel?


Problem: Not able to figure out how to connect to each of the different registries using the Service Connection in Powershell script

Each service connection will be used to connect to a single container registry.
By default Azure DevOps YAML pipeline jobs run in parallel, so if you want to build and push different Docker images to different registries in parallel, use a job for each one.
If for some reason you need to limit the number of parallel jobs that can run simultaneously, consider using a matrix strategy.

You misunderstand, I have exactly 1 agent job have multiple tasks in it. those tasks need to run in parallel, i understand its not possible right now which is why I want to focus on PS script alternative I proposed
Also for now assume I cannot have multiple agent jobs

@MuditBalooja you cannot use one service connection in more than one task. You can use multiple service connections in multiple tasks in the same job, but the tasks will run sequentially, not in parallel. Your best option is to run a separate job for each Docker image/service connection, as I suggested in my answer.

What i wanted to basically figure out if i can pull the creds off the service connection in the ADO project and use it to login to the container registry (all thru powershell script)

@MuditBalooja I wouldn't recommend that, you're complicating things. The main purpose of using service connections is to simplify the authentication to some services/systems, so that you won't have to handle it yourself.

My main end goal is to parallelize the "push image" tasks i have. If not above approach then any other idea? (NOT convert to Jobs)

Hi @MuditBalooja, Have you got a chance to test my pipeline to use single ARM service connection to push images to different ACRs via a PowerShell Core script? Hope the workaround works for you.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT the problem is that one of the OP's container registries is not hosted on Azure.

Thanks a lot for the kind reminder. I overlooked that information. How embarrassing. :)

@AlvinZhao-MSFT nothing to be embarrassed about - we're only humans :-)

Instead of referencing multiple service connections, you may test with one single ARM service connection in one single AzureCLI task, whose underlying service principal is granted with permissions to push images to multiple ACRs. Since the single PowerShell session will authenticate against this service principal, you don't have to get its credential and just run az acr login to different ACRs to tag and push images.
Following that direction, you may try running this sample YAML pipeline below.
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMSvcCnnWIFRootOwner' # The underlying servicep principal of the ARM service conneciton has sufficient permissions to perform push action to multiple ACRs
    scriptType: 'pscore' # Use ForEach-Object -Parallel PowerShell Core 7
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $sampleImage = "hello-world:latest"
      docker pull $sampleImage
      docker images

      $ACRs = @("xxacr1xx", "xxacr2xx")

      # Push the Docker image to each ACR in parallel
      $ACRs | ForEach-Object -Parallel {

          # Login to the ACR
          az acr login --name $_

          # Tag the Docker image
          $tagetImage = $_ + ".azurecr.io/test/repo:$(Build.BuildId)"
          Write-Host Tag $tagetImage
          docker tag $using:sampleImage $tagetImage

          # Push the Docker image
          docker push $tagetImage
      }




my use case has 1 registry in azure and 2 in gcp, having one SPN for all three is not possible

Sorry for the oversight. I am not so familiar with gcp auth workflow as ACR. If possible, you may authenticate access to gcp in script as well. Otherwise, please refer to the suggestion by @RuiJarimba. Thx.
